# How to find system(local) IP address in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ip-address

I'm working on a project.In that we can register complaints to the IT department about system failure or software failure.
In our company each computer is having unique system(local)IP address

I want my complaint to be registered with that address, by which IT person can identify my system and repair it.
I found many on SO but none solved my problem. Are there any solutions for that? Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: Since there is now a bounty on this; is there any reason my suggestion to use CGI Variables did not work out?  Specifically accessing the REMOTE_ADDR server variable inside of your server side ASP.NET code?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Ya I dint know  this limitation from Adobe. I have used REMOTE_ADDR in C# Web Service its working. So to get an system IP I have to call that .Net service from Flex which is bit uncomfortable.

Comment: I'm sorry it makes you uncomfortable, but it is what it is. Are you going to accept an answer and/or award the bounty or let the bounty rep expire?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com sure i will accept answer. By offering bouny I knew many new concepts as the views increased like http://books.google.co.in/books?id=iNVFVenMtEYC&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=Domain+Name+System+(DNS)+IP+address+records+in+flex&source=bl&ots=aooTO3ua0c&sig=c6tvpg48vFIHd9_pOoBhn90BuGI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4XAVT73QC4OrrAfO68DpAQ&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8f6c0-7ffe.html#WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b04a6701d612482d399e5-7fff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify if this was a browser based app or a desktop based AIR App.

The browser based Flash Player will not have access to the IP Address.  However, when the Flash Player pings remote services, the IP Address of the request is usually available to that request as a CGI variable.  How you access those CGI variables will depend upon the server side language of your choice.

I do not believe that AIR has native access to the IP Address either, however you should be able to get access to it using something like NativeProcess or Native Extensions.  You'll have to write some operating system specific code to get at it though.

Comment: My application is browser based. I don't have much idea about CGI variables and NativeProcess, any way thanks for response... :) If it is possible using .Net webservice how to do that?

Comment: You can get access to the network interface in AIR ([source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8f6c0-7ffe.html#WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b04a6701d612482d399e5-8000)) which will give you a list of network devices and their properties (e.g., IP addresses) but it doesn't seem to give you info ala "this is your current IP".

Comment: NativeProcess or Native Extensions are only available to AIR Apps.  In ASP.NET it looks like you can use server variables: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp .  Look into REMOTE_ADDR

Comment: I commonly use whatismyip.com for doing this as a person not as a script, however they do have this page: http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp and a policy page: http://www.whatismyip.com/faq/automation.asp ultimately you probably want to have control of the server doing this and as stated it can be done in basically any server side code since the packets coming through will have the IP source set.  Similarly this might be an option http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php

Answer (score 4):

this is the way I get the ip-address from a Flex AIR client:

```
public static function getClientIPAddress (version:String):String {
        var ni:NetworkInfo = NetworkInfo.networkInfo;
        var interfaceVector:Vector.<NetworkInterface> = ni.findInterfaces();
        var currentNetwork:NetworkInterface;

        for each (var networkInt:NetworkInterface in interfaceVector) {
            if (networkInt.active) {
                for each (var address:InterfaceAddress in networkInt.addresses) {
                    if (address.ipVersion == version) {
                        return address.address;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: OK. thanks. My actual requirement was in flex web application.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this through Flash Player alone.  At this point, you just have to accept that as the final answer.  There is not much point in putting a bounty on this . . . if you Google for this, you will find many experts in Flash are frustrated by this limitation from Adobe.

**The other answer is correct** . . . that is, there are ways to do this if you use Adobe Air, or else non-Adobe methods like CGI, PHP, Java, .NET, etc.

If you want to ask a question about how to do this in .NET, please post it in another question.  (Your question as initially asked is a good one, and should be kept on SO as is.)